# how can I change a byte list from decimal to hex?

Tags: python, arrays, ascii, data-conversion, bytebuffer

basically, I have a list of bytes, and I want to convert that to ASCII text

so I converted that list into a single bytearray (I apologize if that's the wrong term), to then be able to convert it into ASCII text

but since that list has the values seen as decimal, I have issues to convert it to text, since i would need them to be in hex. (obs: the values are in hex, they are just not represented as it)

ok, so this is the initial list:

```
text_bytes_list = [b'74', b'68', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'61', b'20', b'74', b'65', b'73', b'74']
```

and I did this to get it all in a single byte:

```
text_byte = b''.join(text_byte_list)
print(text_byte)
```

the output is: *b'7468697320697320612074657374'*

so what I wanted was a way to turn this:

```
text_bytes_list = [b'74', b'68', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'61', b'20', b'74', b'65', b'73', b'74']
```

into this:

```
text_bytes_list = [b'0x74', b'0x68', b'0x69', b'0x73', b'0x20', b'0x69', b'0x73', b'0x20', b'0x61', b'0x20', b'0x74', b'0x65', b'0x73', b'0x74']
```

so when I joined the list, using the same process I would get:

```
text_byte = b''.join(text_byte_list)
print(text_byte)
```

output: *b'\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74'*

with that value I can convert it into text (my objective here), doing this:

```
text_byte = b'\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74'
print(text_byte.decode("ascii"))
```

the output should be: *this is a test*

sorry, the post got a little big, but I appreciate any help I can get, pls help :)

Comment: Why do you have `text_bytes_list` like that? That is very strange. Looks like something already went wrong and could be fixed instead so you wouldn't even have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert them to integers, and then into a "bytes" string.

```
>>> text_bytes_list = [b'74', b'68', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'69', b'73', b'20', b'61', b'20', b'74', b'65', b'73', b'74']
>>> tbl = [int(t,16) for t in text_bytes_list]
>>> tbl
[116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116]
>>> bytes(tbl)
b'this is a test'
>>>
```

Comment: oh I see, so there's also an even simpler way to get the text. Thank you so much, you helped me a lot